# flask app crashing when importing mail from app

Tags: python, email, flask

I have a flask application, where I want to make an E-mail system so that the user is getting sent an email. So I have made two imports:

```
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail
```

however, whenever I import email from the app, I get this error, whenever I try to run my application.

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (routes) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually associate mail with your app.

Depending on your flask-app construction (here is an app factory version):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
mail = Mail()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    mail.init_app(app)
    return app
app = create_app()
```

Now `app` has a mail object to import. This was not apparent from your code and simply importing something that does not exist yet will generate errors.